# How to separate two or more digits number and add them separately

Tags: java, android, integer

I want to do an activity that if I have a certain integer for ex. 456 I want it to separate this integer to 4, 5, 6 and add separately like 4+5+6 and add it until the last result is equal to or less than 9 or to a single digit number.

for example:

4+5+6=15, now 15 is also a 2 digits number now again it separate 15 as 1, 5 and add 1+5 i.e. 6

So I have to get final result in a single digit number.

How can I achieve this in Java or Android?

**This is the following code I have tried:**

```
if(sum > 9)
{
    int numbers = 0;
    int number = sum;
    int[] digits = getDigitsOf(number);

    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        numbers = (digits[i]);
    }

    tv.setText(numbers);
}
```

**And the function is:**

```
public int[] getDigitsOf(int num)
{        
    int digitCount = Integer.toString(num).length();

    if (num < 0) 
        digitCount--;           

    int[] result = new int[digitCount];

    while (digitCount-- >0) {
        result[digitCount] = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }        
    return result;
}
```

I'm not getting the desired results.

Comment: Did you already try something? It is best to post some code which you think should work, but for some reason does not what you want. Hint for your question: use the modulo and the division operators to separate the digits.

Comment: If you had googled for this you would have got the answer

Comment: @abhay kumar I have goggled this but only find to show the digits separately. Can't find how to add them until the result is in one digit number

Comment: [Algorithm](http://learning-computer-programming.blogspot.in/2007/06/method-of-adding-individual-digits-of.html) [Code](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_write_a_java_program_that_sums_the_digits_of_an_integer_and_optimizes_it_to_single_digit)

Answer (score 2):

You should have learned 
[recursive programming](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-recurs/index.html) and also the use of percentage "%" operator to find each digit in a number

```
 456%10 = 6;// which is the remainder
```

please use both these and find your answer.

This is an easy program. Try around with both the ideas and the answer will click for you

**EDIT:**
i would prefer such a logic

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 456;
    System.out.println(splitnumberAndSum(number));

}

private static int splitnumberAndSum(int number) {
    int sum = 0;
    int rem;
    while (number>0) {
        rem=number%10;
        sum+=rem;
       number /= 10;
    }
    if(sum>9){
        sum = splitnumberAndSum(sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question.. i achieved to separate the number.. but not able to add them separately..

Comment: @MohitRakhra this is what i had expected from your side. you where missing the sum variable for doing the logic.

Comment: @MohitRakhra dont try to convert a number to String. it is costly to do any logic using String

Answer (score 1):

```
String str_no="1235";
String answer="";


 while (check_sum() > 9)
 {
            calc_sum();
 }

    Log.w("final value...",answer); 

public void calc_sum()
{

        int temp=0;
        String temp_str="";

    for (int i=0;i<str_no.length();i++)
        {
                try
                {
                    temp_str=""+str_no.charAt(i);
                    temp=temp+Integer.parseInt(temp_str);
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
        }

        str_no=""+temp;


}

public int check_sum()
{
        int temp=0;
        String temp_str="";
        for (int i=0;i<str_no.length();i++)
        {
            try
            {
                temp_str=""+str_no.charAt(i);
                temp=temp+Integer.parseInt(temp_str);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        answer=""+temp;
        return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try something like following:-

```
int var = 0, sum = 0;
System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try {
    var = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Value of var is: " + var);
do
{
    sum=0;
    while(var>0)
    {
        sum += var%10;
        var = var/10;
    }
    var = sum;
} while(var>10); 
System.out.println("Sum of digits is: " + var);
```

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int num = 656869787;
        String numStr = num+"";
        while(Integer.parseInt(numStr)>9){
            numStr = addDigits(numStr);
        }
        System.out.print(numStr);
    }

    private static String addDigits(String numStr) {
        int sum = 0;
        char[] arr = numStr.toCharArray();
        for(char c : arr){
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(c+"");
        }
        return sum+"";
    }
```